# Shiro + Stormpath get current user in servlet

Tags: java, servlets, shiro, stormpath

I have just started to use Apache Shiro and Stormpath. In the jsp's everything is working fine and as expected. But how can I get the current user data and his custom fields within a servlet?

```
@WebServlet("/test")
public class Foo extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        Subject currentUser = SecurityUtils.getSubject();
        Session session = currentUser.getSession();

        // how to get username and custom fields hereg??
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get all the available user data for the current `Subject` this way:

```
Map<String, String> userAttributes = SecurityUtils.getSubject().getPrincipals().oneByType(java.util.Map.class);
System.out.println("Account href: " + userAttributes.get("href"));
System.out.println("Username: " + userAttributes.get("username"));
// other attributes available
```

In case you also want to manipulate actual Stormpath Resources (like `Account` and `CustomData`):

```
ApplicationRealm realm = ((ApplicationRealm)((RealmSecurityManager) SecurityUtils.getSecurityManager()).getRealms().iterator().next());
Client client = realm.getClient(); //The Client object is what allows you to communicate with Stormpath
Account account = client.getResource(userAttributes.get("href"), Account.class); //The actual Stormpath Account object belonging to the current Subject
CustomData customData = account.getCustomData();
//or, if you want to obtain the CustomData without first retrieving the Account, thus avoiding an unnecessary server hit:
//CustomData customData = client.getResource(userAttributes.get("href") + "/customData", CustomData.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use the new `stormpath-servlet-plugin` you just need to do:

```
Account account = AccountResolver.INSTANCE.getAccount(request);
```

Typically you'd call this within your `HttpServlet.doGet(...)` or `doPost(...)` method.

See [this Stormpath blog post](https://stormpath.com/blog/java-webapp-instant-user-management/) for more details.

However it's currently (October 5th, 2015) a bit of a mess if you're using Shiro as the latest `stormpath-shiro-core` is `0.6.0` which depends on a `stormpath-sdk-api` version that is not compatible with the one required by any of the available `stormpath-servlet-plugin` versions.

Presumably this will be resolved once they release the final non-RC version of the plugin.

If you look at the blog post and the [full plugin documentation](https://docs.stormpath.com/java/servlet-plugin/) you *might* decide though that you can do without Shiro.